# what PDF creator do you use with laravel?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel, dompdf

I've heard that DOMPDF is a good choice, but I want to know if you outhere use a better aproach with DOMPDF or a better PDF creator.

I made a test with DOMPDF, but it's not stable using headers with special characters for example.

Comment: actually off-topic, but as one of the duplicate questions is still open, a dupe. Why off-topic? Stackoverflow is not a good format for giving advice kind of questions for what is best X/Y/Z as those answers a subjective. Such questions are generally to be prevented as they attract low quality answers. What's probably more fitting is to really ask about the concrete problem you have and provide a dedicated code-example to reproduce the issue.